# How to convert pointer value to a string

Tags: delphi

How is it possible to convert pointer value to the string? Imagine it like:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var DummyPointer :Pointer;
begin
  DummyPointer := Addr(Sender);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(DummyPointer)); //this is it, what I can not solve... it casts error
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: What's a `TPointer`?

Comment: Cast pointer to an integer with the same size as a pointer: `IntToStr(NativeInt(DummyPointer));`

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand TPointer is a typo... I corrected it...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you write `TPointer`, but I assume you mean [`Pointer`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Pointers_and_Pointer_Types_(Delphi)).

Now, given a pointer `P`, the trick is to reinterpret this as a native-sized integer: `NativeInt(P)`, for instance. [`NativeInt`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.NativeInt) is a signed integer type with the same size as a pointer.

Hence, the following compiles:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DummyPointer: Pointer;
begin
  DummyPointer := Addr(Sender);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(NativeInt(DummyPointer)));
end;
```

This will display the address of the `Sender` variable.

However, this *might* not be what you want. I suspect you want the address of the object that `Sender` points at instead. Indeed, in Delphi, an object variable is simply a pointer to the object on the heap:

```pascal
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  DummyPointer: Pointer;
begin
  DummyPointer := Addr(Sender);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(NativeInt(DummyPointer))); // address to the Sender variable
  DummyPointer := Pointer(Sender);
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(NativeInt(DummyPointer))); // address to the Sender object
  ShowMessage(IntToStr(NativeInt(Sender)));       // address to the Sender object
end;
```

The difference is that at `Addr(Sender)` you find a pointer variable to the `Sender` object, while at `Pointer(Sender)` you find the object itself.

Comment: I face to the hard debugging problem. That's why I want to inspect the references, if they correctly point to the appropriate instances of objects (or not)... I think, the right answer should be Addr(Sender)... thank you for the explanation...

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var 
    DummyPointer :TPointer;
begin
    DummyPointer := Addr(Sender);
    ShowMessage(IntToStr(UIntPtr(DummyPointer)));
end;
```

For Delphi 7, use:

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Cardinal(DummyPointer)));
```

Comment: This depends on what a `TPointer` is.

Comment: Unfortunately I can not confirm your answer, while my Delphi 7 do not recognize the type UIntPtr... But from the logical point of view it should be the right answer. IntToStr(NativeInt(DummyPointer)); seems to work fine... thanks anyway...

Comment: Since Delphi 7 is 32 bit only, you can use a cast to Cardinal instead. When using such old compiler, you should really use the correct tag in your question.

Comment: @fpiette I admit I should be more precise... Next time I will tag my questions correctly...

Comment: Do not use NativeInt but NativeUInt or Cardinal: using a signed integer can cause trouble in some situation where addresses are above 2GB. Casting to an integer makes it a negative number.

Comment: Yes, using unsigned is slightly better, at least semantically. (But today I don't think there *can* be an issue, and it would only be visual.)